# WFFM: dynamically populated dependent drop lists

Tags: wffm

I have the requirement to create two lists: the second one being dynamically populated with Sitecore data after the user selects a value from the first one. 
I tried using some Rules for WFFM but can't seem to match any with what I want to have as results.

I would like to have something like countries in the first list. After selecting a value, the second list will dynamically populate the regions depending on the country selected - if the country has regions, else a N/A single element will be added.

What is the best way and approach for doing this dependent drop lists functionality for a WFFM form (Sitecore 8.1 - webforms)?

Comment: I suspect you're going to need some custom field types to achieve this.  Bolt in some JS that calls a back-end REST service to populate the drop-downs, or if there are only a small number of permutations, send all the data in a JSON block to the glass and let JS do the work of re-populating the drop-downs.  A couple of decent blogs on the topic include [Creating a custom field type in wffm for sitecore](https://soen.ghost.io/creating-a-custom-field-type-in-wffm-for-sitecore) and [WFFM Session Aware Single-Line Text Field](https://sitecorecorner.com/tag/wffm-custom-field)

Comment: Yes totally agree with Richard Hauer, I also had the same requirement to populate states according to country selection in WFFM, what I did is I have created 2 Dropdown fields in WFFM and hide states DD. And with the help of javascript I have populated country list in DD, and on the selection of country, I used JSON to show appropriate state DD.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal how did you passed the invalid state error on submit? I also did the implementation of WFFM dependent droplist by using js but now I get a invalid state error on postback of the form since the droplists are populated via js and not in code. Is there a way you managed to bypass that error?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure I came across an example of linked drop downs in WFFM in the past but can't find find it now. This might be a good basis to start from: http://sitecoreguild.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/sitecore-country-and-region-dropdowns.html

However you will obviously need to inherit from the right classes for your dropdowns to work, there is a good example here: https://divamatrix.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/wffm-custom-field-type-made-easy/

Comment: There isn't any substance to this answer, merely external links. I don't believe this meets the guidelines for a good answer.