# WFFM web form errors on first submission but succeeds on second try every time; 'Sequence contains more than one matching element'

Tags: wffm, webforms, sitecore-forms

I have a form that I'm using on several different language pages. The English page with the form works without issue. I also have the form on a Dutch and Spanish page, and I've created corresponding language versions of the form. When I try to submit the form on either of these language pages, I consistently get an error the first time (the form page reloads with an error message "We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved."). I see this error when I check the logs:

> Web Forms for Marketers: an exception 'Sequence contains more than one
>   matching element' has occured while trying to execute an action ''.

If I then click the submit button again, it works.

I'm also having trouble debugging this because I cannot replicate the behavior on my local environment. All I have to go on is the 'Sequence contains more than one matching element' error, and I'm not sure what that's referring to or why it works the second time.

**Edit 1**: The issue is with my States field. I have a field for states that displays/is required *if* the country selected is US. I think the error is from trying to submit an empty value for State when the country is not US

**Edit 2**: The error occurs with the States field even when an option is selected, so it's not a matter of the field being blank. I think it's an issue with the data it's using, though I'm not sure what the problem is

So, my state field is a custom field. It is empty on page load and then populates once the country is selected by pulling a list of states/provinces for the selected country from Sitecore. There are different lists for USA, Canada, Australia, etc so I cannot just set it to US states and hide/display. I removed the custom validation, which it turns out wasn't even doing anything.

The states list functions just like what's described in this post: [WFFM: dynamically populated dependent drop lists](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27/wffm-dynamically-populated-dependent-drop-lists)

[image]

Comment: this kind of issue appear when you have custom validation form. Can you try to remove all validation forms and submit again. If it's working add validation forms one by one

Comment: I did, the issue is still happening. I had one custom Verification method and two Save actions (send to Eloqua and Redirect). I removed all of these one by one but the error is still happening.

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert Have you published the whole site after removing validation? Can you specify in your question version of Sitecore and WFFM module? Also can you can screenshot of state field and options it has?

Comment: @PeterProchazka yes I did. I am using Sitecore 8.2 and WFFM 8.2

Comment: @PeterProchazka I added a screenshot and some more details

Comment: Can you try to remove duplicate option values, there are currently multiple same values like New, North and South

Comment: @EricaStockwell-Alpert I would just consolidate list of options and make that valid. You have two "South" values but after these values you have "Carolina" and "Dakota" which is wrong. This is causing you trouble

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice that!

Comment: Crossposting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576024/sitecore-wffm-web-form-errors-on-first-submission-but-succeeds-on-second-try-eve

Answer (score 1):

Your list of values for states is not valid and that is causing you trouble.
Instead of South Carolina and South Dakota you are using same value "South" and that's why you have duplicates. "Carolina" and "Dakota" are not part of value.
Text part / Display name is rendered correctly. Only problem is with Value field.

You have the same also for states that start with "New" and "North".

Comment: Fixing that seemed to resolve the issue. I'm just confused why the same problem happened when I selected a country where the states list was empty.

Comment: I would assume that it could be caused by that faulthy validation that you had there before..